# Why are some happiness motives starred?

Tags: tropico-3

When watching at people happiness motives I can see that some of them are starred. At first I thought they just had an higher weight when calculating the overall happiness but it seems it's not the case: sometimes even motives with weight 5 are starred.

So what is the meaning of the "star"? Does it mean a more important motive somehow? But more important how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The starred motives indicate, as you've said, what that particular person cares about more heavily than other motives.

Starred motives directly influence a person's satisfaction/happiness with you and your island, and will determine whether they leave (assuming you allow them to), or turn Rebel. This is not to say that if you satisfy all of their starred needs but completely ignore every other one that they will be happy.

This information can be particularly useful when you start to see peaceful protests or when faction leaders are unhappy.

Comment: So it's a kind of weight modifier or something like that. It would be nice to know if the star is more important than the weight (i.e. if a starred motive with weight 5 is more important that an unstarred motive with weight 10) but I guess that there isn't a very huge impact on gameplay after all.

Comment: @happy_emi I'm not sure what the actual modification value is, but it definitely amounts to a larger individual rating than the others. Overall, you're better off just making sure that everyone has adequate amounts of everything. The only time I truly use those starred ratings as guidance is when I need to sway a faction leader before an upcoming election or when I see that protests are occurring in rapid succession.